# How can I determine if user input is a valid hexadecimal number? 

Tags: python

```
#Hex Check
def Check():
    while False:
        for char in UserInput:
            if char not in Valid:
                print ('That is an invalid hex value.')
        print('That is a valid hex value.')
        return Check

UserInput=input('Enter a hex number: ')
Valid='1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''A''B''C''D''E''F'
```

EDIT: I've tried this. When I enter a hex value e.g. B2 no message comes up.

Comment: There are no invalid combinations of hexadecimal digits, just as there are no invalid combinations of decimal digits. You just have to check if all the characters in the user input are members of the set {0-9, A-F}

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is because your `Check()` function is never called.

Comment: Would I call it in a print statement?

Comment: Please explain *exactly* what you want your script to do. Do you want the user to input a value and tell the user whether it is a valid hex number? Do you want the program to keep asking until it receives a valid hex number?

Comment: You already have print statements within check() so that's not necessary. Just insert the line `Check()` after` UserInput = ...`, or if you plan on doing something with the user input after the check, insert `someVariable = Check()` instead.

Comment: You also don't need to write Valid as 'A''B''C''...  you can include everything in one set of quotation marks: `Valid = "ABCDEF0123..."`

Comment: Still not working though! It doesn't give an error, just doesn't provide an output. I'm unsure where to call Check(). It doesn't work after the UserInput line

Comment: If this is a homework, please consider adding  a 'homework' tag...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Program not displaying as intended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675229/python-program-not-displaying-as-intended)

Answer (score 7):

Change line 6 to

```
Hex=int(input('Enter a hex number: '), 16)
```

This line would successfully parse any hexadecimal input (for example, '0x123f') and would throw a ValueError on an invalid input (such as 'hello').

ETA: Based on your comments, the following is all you need:

```
user_input = input('Enter a hex number: ')
try:
    hexval = int(user_input, 16)
    print 'That is a valid hex value.'
except:
    print 'That is an invalid hex value.'
```

ETA: If you really have to have a `Check` function, this structure would be the best way to do it:

```
import re

def Check(s):
    """Check if a string is a valid hexadecimal number"""
    # code for checking if it is a valid hex number here

user_input = raw_input("Enter a hex number: ")
if Check(user_input):
    print 'That is a valid hex value.'
else:
    print 'That is an invalid hex value.'
```

Since this is a homework question *I'm not going to finish the answer*- just know that the `Check` function has to return True if the string is a valid hex statement or False if the string is not.

There are many ideas among everyone's answers of how to do it, and you could indeed use a try/except statement like I do above. One of the best ways to do it would be to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which are a very powerful way to parse strings.

Comment: If the question specifically asks for a hex number, I would explicitly use base `16` in the call to `int()`.

Comment: I use a newer version of python which doesn't use raw input, just input

Comment: And upon running it, no input message appears unless I type Check()

Comment: Sure, I changed it to input. I don't understand your second comment- do you mean when you run it in an interpreter? Of course this behavior will only happen when you run the Check() function.

Comment: Your new code won't ever check your input, because you never call the Check function (just defining it doesn't do anything). Also, the purpose of your `while False` loop, as well as the `return Check` statement, is completely unclear. Please state *clearly* the exact behavior you want your script to have.

Comment: Good answer, didn't know this functionality of `int()`. +1

Comment: I want the script to ask the user to enter a hexidecimal number. If the hex number is valid, it will output "That is a valid hex number." If it is invalid, it will out" That is an invalid hex number" That is all it needs to do

Comment: Thanks, that works but I don't know how. You haven't listed what is allowed to be hexidecimal in terms of letters and numbers, which confuses me.
What does this line do? hexval = int(user_input, 16)

Comment: It's also prefferable that a function called 'Check' is used.

Comment: That converts the user input string into an int. The second argument, 16, asks that it be converted in base 16 (hexadecimal). If it is not a valid hexadecimal string, it will raise a ValueError, which the `except` catches.

Comment: Why does it matter that a function called `Check` is used? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Yes it is a HWK problem. Check() is prefferable.

Thanks, I understand now. If possible though, I'd like to find out where mines going wrong. I'm new to this so apologies with slow catching on. I don't understand where'd you call Check.

Comment: Gahh it just doesn't make sense to me... I don't know why mine doesn't work or where to define Check.

Comment: I provide a proposed structure in my answer, including the definition of Check. Yours doesn't work because you never call the Check function. You need to read tutorials and documentation on Python functions, including arguments and return values, so that you are comfortable using them.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the regex library.  Or do explicit cast to int then catch any errors and process them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid values for hex strings are `0-9, A-F`  .  It should be possible to store these values in a list / array and then do a simple contains call.  Something along the lines of this:

```
  for char in userInput:  
      if not char in validTokens:  
          print 'invalid hex value'
```

Comment: What about the 0x at the start?

Comment: User shouldn't have to supply it.

Comment: I've used something similar although I have changed "if not char in" to "if char not in" because it sounds more logical in English, but is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice, Python way to check your input for a valid hex number.

```
def Check():
    while not Valid:
        try:
            Hex=int(raw_input('Enter a hex number: '), 16)
            print('That is valid.')
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print('That is an invalid entry.')
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question from a Python philosophy point of view, because you have already received good answers, some of them involving `try: .. except`.

The Pythonic thing about using exception handling `try: .. except` is the way Python programmers seem to be encouraged to use it is, at least for me, a departure from exception handling in other languages.

In Python, you are encouraged to raise an exception, either explicitly using raise or more implicitly within the construct of try .. except.

When I posed a question a while back about how to deal with null integer values in a .csv file, I was encouraged to go ahead with the assignment to the Python integer variable within try: .. except, instead of testing first to test to see if the value was null.

The answer went on to say don't bother to test and then take action, use exception handling, because it is more Pythonic. Using try: .. except also appeared to consume fewer instructions.

That attitude got me to write more exception handling than I would have thinking using try: .. except was reserved only for when bad things happen.

Answer (score 0):

The expression
   string.translate(x, None, "0123456789abcdefABCDEF") == ''
is True iff x contains valid hexadecimal characters, or x is the null string.(You need to "import string".)
   Obviously this can be used to validate that a string contains only characters from any given set (or is null).