# Python program isn't displaying an output

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if user input is a valid hexadecimal number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672615/how-can-i-determine-if-user-input-is-a-valid-hexadecimal-number) 
>   [Python - Program not displaying as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675229/python-program-not-displaying-as-intended)

```
#Hex Check
def Check(HexInput):
    while True:
        if HexInput in Valid:
            print('That is a valid hex number.')
        else:
            print('That is an invalid hex number.')
        return HexInput       

HexInput=input('Enter a hex number: ')
Valid='1234567890ABCDEFG'
```

Program needs to contain Check(). It should ask the user to input a hex number and tell them whether it's a valid hex number or not.

Comment: Note that `'1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''A''B''C''D''E''F'` is simply `'12345678910ABCDEF'` and the second `1` in that is not needed.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so, please use the [homework] tag.

Comment: You will get a lot further if you don't ask for someone to write the code for you. Suggest you ask for help in determining what is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672615/how-can-i-determine-if-user-input-is-a-valid-hexadecimal-number        Best not to repost the same question over and over as you work on it.  Stick to one thread.

Comment: So... how did you get the code to this point?

Comment: I just did what I thought would work. When the program is run it doesnt output anything when numbers/letters are entered, which is confusing me

Comment: Note that hex doesn't have a 'G'

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
while False:
```

will never execute. You can use "while True:" or "while checked == False:" but not "while False:"

Your Check() function must also take in parameters so that it looks like

```
def Check(UserInput, Valid):
```

You also need an additional "if" statement because even if the user inputs an invalid hex value, the program will still print "That is a valid hex value."

Next,

```
return Check
```

does not make sense as you do not have any variable named "Check"

Finally, you must actually call your function like so:

```
Check(UserInput, Valid)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do in your program but for start , `while False:` mean that the code in the while loop will always be ignored (not executed)

Comment: I want to ask the user to input a hexidecimal number and if its a valid one, ouput "Valid hex number" and if not, output "Invalid hex number" Loop doesn't matter

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: Edited program with while True, can you check?

Answer (score 0):

The body of the while False: will never execute.

```
while False:
  print("You will never enter this loop.")
  .
  .
  .
```

This will execute, but you have to make sure you test for a condition, 
so you can break out of the loop. That is you do not want to loop endlessly.

```
while True:
      print("You will enter this loop.")
      print("Make sure you test for a condition that will let you "break".)
      break
```

Edit: You asked me to check your program. There are still some problems.

Use raw_input instead of input. The Python Tutorial at http://docs.python.org suggested raw_input.

The way you've written your program, if you have a multi-digit number, you'd need to check each digit, and that's what Python's for is for.

I've written something crude. In my version you'd test for 0 or non-zero. If
zero, you don't have a hex number. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

I strongly suggest fiddling with code in the Python command line. That's what it's for.

```
def Check(HexInput):
    valid_hex_digit = 0 #Assume invalid
    for digit in HexInput:
        if digit in Valid:
            valid_hex_digit = valid_hex_digit + 1
        else:
            error_str = "Invalid hex digit " + str(digit) + " found."
            print(error_str)
            valid_hex_digit = 0
            break

    return valid_hex_digit
```

Comment: Can you check my edited program?